# how to programmatically add a new relativelayout after another relativelayout without overlap?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I tried to programmatically add a new relativelayout after another relativelayout without overlap.

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLL);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);       

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    rl.setId(2);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);//RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ll.addView(rl, lp);  

    TextView iTextView = new TextView(this);         
    iTextView.setTextSize(pthTextFontSize);
    iTextView.setText("ok"); 
    rl.addView(iTextView);       
    // finish adding the first relativelayout.


    RelativeLayout rl2 = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);    
    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, rl.getId());
    rl2.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    ll.addView(rl2);

    TextView iTextView2 = new TextView(this);         
    iTextView2.setTextSize(pthTextFontSize);
    iTextView2.setText("abc"); 
    rl.addView(iTextView2);
```

However, the word "ok" and "abc" are overlapped. Can anyone help me to check what is wrong?
Thank a lot for help.

In short:
There is a linearlayout(occupied the full screen). Then I try to add two linearlayouts.The parent of relative layout "rl2" is "ll", and i tried to put "rl2" at ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT of "ll", and below "rl1", but they overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test your code but seeing the logic, the problem might be because you have used ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT for Relative Layout 2. Just to explain briefly, the parent of relative layout "rl2" is rl1. So, the text "abc" ( in rl2) is being aligned in the rl1's leftmost part, where "ok" exists. That's why they overlap. I haven't tried it myself but try using:

```
lp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

Tell me if it helps. All the best

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use your code but they still overlap. I guess i did not mention the problem clear enough. In fact, there is a linearlayout(occupied the full screen). Then I try to add two linearlayouts. So i guess the parent of relative layout "rl2" is "ll", and i tried to put "rl2" at ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT of "ll", and below "rl1", but they overlap. Please help, thanks!